# NextJS and Prisma (MongoDB) Error: Invalid Invocation

Tags: database, mongodb, next.js, prisma, next.js13

I have been following an online tutorial for a NextJS e-commerce website made by Coding in Flow. Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaiijESQH5o&t=2885s.

Everything was going smoothly until I had to update my Prisma schema. After updating, this error showed up:

`Error:  Invalid 'prisma.cart.findUnique()' invocation:`

`Error converting field "updatedAt" of expected non-nullable type "DateTime", found incompatible value of "null".`

Here is the code in lib/db/cart.ts

```
export async function getCart(): Promise<ShoppingCart | null> {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  let cart: CartWithProducts | null = null;

  if (session) {
    cart = await prisma.cart.findFirst({
      where: { userId: session.user.id },
      include: { items: { include: { product: true } } },
    });
 } else {
    const localCartId = cookies().get("localCartId")?.value;
    cart = localCartId
      ? await prisma.cart.findUnique({
          where: { id: localCartId },
          include: { items: { include: { product: true } } },
       })
       : null;
  }

  if (!cart) {
    return null;
  }

  return {
    ...cart,
    size: cart.items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity, 0),
    subtotal: cart.items.reduce(
      (acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.product.price,
      0
    ),
  };
}
```

My Prisma schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Product {
  id          String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  description String
  imageUrl    String
  name        String
  price       Int
  createdAt   DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime   @updatedAt
  CartItem    CartItem[]

  @@map("products")
}

model Cart {
  id        String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  items     CartItem[]
  userId    String?    @db.ObjectId
  user      User?      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  createdAt DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime   @updatedAt

  @@map("carts")
}

model CartItem {
  id        String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  productId String  @db.ObjectId
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  quantity  Int
  cartId    String  @db.ObjectId
  cart      Cart    @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("cartitems")
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId            String  @db.ObjectId
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.String
  access_token      String? @db.String
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.String
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
  @@map("accounts")
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String   @db.ObjectId
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("sessions")
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  Cart          Cart[]

  @@map("users")
}

model VerificationToken {
  id         String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
  @@map("verificationtokens")
}
```

I have have read up on how to solve this and it might have something to do with 'localCartId' being null when being called but I don't know where to really start. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.